# How is this subtracting from 6 to 0?

Tags: python

I got it that it has been adding 2, 4 times so reaching to 6 but why is it going down each by 2 after reaching 6?

```
test = []

def function2(n):
    test.append(n)
    if (n < 5):
        function2(n + 2)
    test.append(n)

function2(0)
print(test)
```

Comment: Because each `n` gets appended *twice*, once before the recursive call that increases `n`, and once after.  It's like a sandwich.  Each pair of new larger values goes right in the middle of the all the previous values.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding some `print`s to your code to help you visualize what's happening when.

```
test = []

def function2(n):
    print(f"{' '*n}function2({n}) start")
    test.append(n)

    if (n < 5):
        function2(n + 2)

    print(f"{' '*n}function2({n}) end")
    test.append(n)

function2(0)
print(test)
```

```
function2(0) start
  function2(2) start
    function2(4) start
      function2(6) start
      function2(6) end
    function2(4) end
  function2(2) end
function2(0) end
[0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just picking the local value of the function parameter n during the unwinding of the recursion.

Example.

```
1. First call --> n=0 | test=[0] | stack frame has n=0
2 .Second call --> n=2 | test=[0, 2] | stack frame has n=2
3 .third call --> n=4 | test=[0, 2, 4] | stack frame has n=4
4. fourth call --> n=4 | test=[0, 2, 4, 6] | recursion stops here

test list becomes, test=[0, 2, 4, 6, 6]

3. from top stack frame (third call's stack frame) --> n=4 | test=[0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 4]
2. from second call's stack frame --> n=2 | test=[0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2]
1. from bottom stack frame (first call's stack frame) --> n=0 | [0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

I hope it helps.